# Is there a way to change the output of the strings based on the conditions of the loop?

Tags: python, string, loops, random, conditional-statements

I hope I worded the question right. So I'm going through a Python textbook. (automate the boring stuff). In it, I am supposed to create a guess the number game in which the player has 6 chances to pick the correct number.

However, I would like to make a couple of changes that I'm struggling with.

1. I want the output to show the exact amount of chances left (6 chances, 5 chances, 4, chances ... 0). I think i may have solved this problem, but I believe you all may have a better way.
2. when the player is down to 1 chance, i would like the text to change from 'chances left' to 'chance left'.

```
# This is a guess the number game.
import random

secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

# Ask the player to guess 6 times.
for guessTaken in range(7, 1, -1):
    print('Take a guess. You only have ' + str(guessTaken - 1) + ' chances left... ')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low. ')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too high. ')
    else:
        break  # This condition is the correct guess

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job! you guessed my number i ' + str(guessTaken) + ' guesses!')
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your range to `range(6, 0, -1)` so you don't need to subtract 1 in the message.
2. Use an `if` statement.

```
for guessTaken in range(6, 0, -1):
    suffix = "s" if guessTaken > 1 else ""
    print('Take a guess. You only have ' + str(guessTaken) + ' chance' + suffix + ' left... ')
```

You're also printing the wrong number in the success message. `guessTaken` is the number of guesses they have left, not the number of guesses they used. You need to change that to `7 - guessTaken`.

Comment: Can you explain why the success message should be 7 - guesstaken. Where did the 7 come from?  (it worked perfectly btw!)

Comment: If they guess right on the first try, `guessTaken` is `6`. `7 - 6 = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Now may be a good time to learn about functions, if you haven't already. A simple function to do this is this:

```py
def chances_remaining_message(num_chances):
    if num_chances == 1:
        return 'Take a guess. You only have 1 chance left...'
    else:
        return 'Take a guess. You only have ' + str(num_chances) + ' chances left...'
```

Which you would then call here:

```py
# Ask the player to guess 6 times.
for guessTaken in range(7, 1, -1):
    print(chances_remaining_message(guessTaken - 1))
    guess = int(input())
```